# ERROR : Must supply api_key when using cloudinary with nestjs

Tags: javascript, html, nestjs, backend

I am writing a simple application in `nestjs` and using `cloudinary` to save product image. And getting error again : Must supply api_key.

```
// cloudinary.provider.ts

import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';
import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';

export const cloudinaryProvider: Provider = {
  
  provide: 'CLOUDINARY',
  useFactory: () => { 
    return cloudinary.config({
      cloud_name: 'dqfjlrs2x',
      api_key: '357184499293337',
      api_secret:'opzf-rnuhGodvhFS3xRPon17COE',
  });
  },
};`
```

If anyone has encountered it and fixed it, please leave some instructions so I can fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please never include your personal credentials in your post.   Since they now have been exposed, please consider having a new set of credentials regenerated and revoke the old ones.

Comment: It seems that you have included your private personal credentials, such as the Cloudinary API key and API secret, in the code snippet. It's crucial to avoid sharing sensitive information like credentials in publicly accessible code, as it can pose security risks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, all I did was restart the nestjs server and the error cleared.